# why NullPointerException with EditText?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Sorry, maybe it is a beginner problem. This is a part of my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
...
        EditText et101 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText101);
...
        public myOwnClass(String my_id){
                et000.setText(my_id)
}
```

why do I get an NPE when I use `et101` in myOwnClass? This is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The error is in that line, where `EditText et101 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText101);` is

Comment: Do you have an EditText with "*editText101*" as id in your xml file?

Comment: yes I do have the editText101 in my xml-file.


as I said before, the error occurs at the beginning of the java-file: `EditText et101 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText101);`

maybe there is the problem?? there is no duplicate :(

Comment: Where you defined et000 in your MainActivity ?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your `EditText` as a class level variable, and initialize it in `onCreate`

Something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et101;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.yourActivity);

    et101 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText101);

    ...
    }

    public void myOwnClass(String my_id){
        et101.setText(my_id)
    }
}
```

This guide in the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) might be a good reference for you

Comment: but my function isn't in the oncreate.So it does'n make sense to do this in the oncreate, or am I wrong. My function is in the `public class MainActivity extends Activity {...}`

Comment: Right, but the first thing that happens when an activity starts is `onCreate`. You were trying to call `findViewById` outside of any function, which causes the NPE. It is a good practice to initialize all of your views in `onCreate`, so you can access them from wherever you want to later on

Comment: By the way, is `myOwnClass` supposed to be a method? You need to specify a return type, or if it doesn't return anything, `void`, like this `public void myOwnClass(String my_id) { et101.setText(my_id); }`

Comment: ok, ich done it. all the `findViewByID` are in the `onCreate` an I declare everything at the beginning of `MainActivity extends Activity`. But that wont help. Now the NPE is on `btnSave11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()`, not on the EditText. But the button is declared and also `findViewById` and the button is in the xml.
Whats the error now ? :`(

btw: yes the return type is void. i just forgot to write it here

Comment: Could you update your original question to have all of your new code?

Comment: my code is like @Andrew Brooke shows it. instead of the NPE at EditText, now the NPE is at `btnSave11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {...` but it is all declared